# C++ getch() in perl?

Tags: perl, getch

In c++, there is a functio, getch(),
which returns the
variable of the key you pressed - like enter would be
13.  How could I do this in perl?

Comment: don't forget to mark answers to this and your other questions.  So far you've marked 2 out of a possible 8. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm).

Comment: Because for the most part Term::ReadKey is problematic under Windows. I've not used it in some years so this situation may have changed. As I understand it, the source was a bit too tightly bound to Unix and POSIX...

Answer (score 5):

in short:

```
$x = ord(getc);
```

detailed:

```
$c = getc(STDIN);
$x = ord($c);
```

from `perldoc -f getc` :

```
"However, it cannot be used by itself to fetch single 
characters without waiting for the user to hit enter. 
For that, try something more like":

   1.  if ($BSD_STYLE) {
   2. system "stty cbreak </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1";
   3. }
   4. else {
   5. system "stty", '-icanon', 'eol', "\001";
   6. }
   7.
   8. $key = getc(STDIN);
   9.
  10. if ($BSD_STYLE) {
  11. system "stty -cbreak </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1";
  12. }
  13. else {
  14. system 'stty', 'icanon', 'eol', '^@'; # ASCII NUL
  15. }
  16. print "\n";
```